# Error Number: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'core_user'

Tags: codeigniter

I have 3 tables in a database.

core_user
core_company
ct_company

i want to join 2 tables core_user and core_company where foriegn key is cmp_id column..

but it shows an error.

Error Number: 1066

Not unique table/alias: 'core_user'

SELECT * FROM (`core_user`, `core_user`) JOIN `core_company` ON `core_company`.`cmp_id` = `core_user`.`cmp_id` WHERE `usr_email` = 'fahad@gmail.com' AND `usr_password` = '123456' AND `cmp_name` = 'corpoleave'

Filename: F:/xampp/htdocs/corpoLeave/application/models/loginmodel.php

Line Number: 10

here is my model. please help. thanks

```
<?php class LoginModel extends CI_Model{

    public function login_valid($email,$password,$cname){


        $q= $this->db->where(['usr_email'=>$email,'usr_password'=>$password,'cmp_name'=>$cname])
                            ->from('core_user');

                            $this->db->join('core_company', 'core_company.cmp_id = core_user.cmp_id');
                            $q = $this->db->get('core_user')->result();
                            if($q->result()==true)
                            {
                                return $q->row()->user_id;


                            }
                            else{

                                return false;
                            }

}}

?>
```

Comment: Just a note if your using CI 3 versions class and file names should only have first letter upper case http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#anatomy-of-a-model

Answer (score 2):

In the Codeigniter Query Builder, the `get()` and `from()` methods perform similarly.

As seen on the [Codeigniter docs](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html):

**get()**

```
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');  
// Produces: SELECT * FROM mytable
```

**from()**

```
$this->db->select('title, content, date');
$this->db->from('mytable');
$query = $this->db->get();  
// Produces: SELECT title, content, date FROM mytable
```

Both the `get("tablename")` and `from("tablename")` methods effectively append `FROM tablename` to the built statement, looking something like this:

```
$this->db->select('title, content, date');
$this->db->from('mytable');
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');  
// Produces: SELECT title, content, date FROM mytable FROM mytable
```

(Notice the double "FROM" statement)

You are getting the error because you are using both `from()` and `get()` with tablenames. You can either remove the `from()` statement, or remove the tablename from the `get()` statement.

This would look like:

```
<?php

class LoginModel extends CI_Model {

    public function login_valid($email, $password, $cname) {
        $this->db->where(['usr_email' => $email, 'usr_password' => $password, 'cmp_name' => $cname]);
        $this->db->from('core_user');
        $this->db->join('core_company', 'core_company.cmp_id = core_user.cmp_id');

        $q = $this->db->get();

        if ($q->result()) {
            return $q->row()->user_id;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```